# How can I add add an exception offset to a memory address?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, memory-address, disassembly

I'm trying to find the source of an APPCRASH and I've learned that you can find the start memory address of the .exe file your running, and add the memory address of the 'Exception offset' onto that and find that address in assembly, to see the line of code causing the problem. I'm not sure how to 'add' memory addresses. The start module of the .exe is at address 00190000-0021D000 - that doesn't look like the memory addresses I know! (It's much longer!)

How do I add 0002207b onto that address to see where the access violation is? (I tried converting both to decimal, adding the decimals, and converting back again, but the result was empty).

Comment: What do you mean the result was empty? The sum of the addresses does not exist? The memory at the address is not accessible? The memory at the address was some sort of value representing an empty object?

Comment: 00190000-0021D000 is a *range*, first and last address of the module.  Use the Windows calculator, switch to Programmer's mode.  0x00190000 + 0x0002207b = 0x001b207b.  Pretty doubtful that the instruction at that address tells you much, ask the user to provide you with a minidump.

Comment: @nwp ?? ?? After the address

Comment: @HansPassant Thank-you very much man! Its pointing to glfw, so I look around there :)